# Managing push notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

i'm implementing push notifications in my app and i've the following proccess:

> Device receive the notification > the user tap on notification > navigate to specific screen.

Searching in the web, i didn't find anything about it.

So, i've tried to implement a listener on receive the notification, but no success.

```
  const _handleReceivedNotification = (notification: Notification) => {
    const { data } = notification.request.content;
    const { request } = notification;
    console.log(data, request); // notification.request.content.data object has '{ screen: "Supply/Order/ApproveOrderDetail/712177" }'
    try {
      props.navigation.navigate("Supply", {
        screen: "Order",
        param: { screen: "ApproveOrderDetail", param: { id: data.id } },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

    const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(
      _handleReceivedNotification
    );

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
      console.log("subscribed");
    };
  }, []);
```

Has anyone implemented this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `react-native-firebase` libraries in your application. This way, you can take the actions you want when your notification is triggered with the code snippet below.

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import '@react-native-firebase/messaging'

firebase.messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((remoteMessage) => {
   if (remoteMessage) {
      // console.log('onNotificationOpenedApp ', remoteMessage)
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try

Comment: For me the imported firebase don't expose the messaging function. What i need to do?

Comment: ok i start to use firebase like that with expo but i got his error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005600/expo-standalone-application-crashes-in-the-splash-screen-when-you-use-the-fireba

Answer (score 0):

If you use Expo, in Expo Doc u have an overview on how to use expo push (with a generate token by expo, u push one time with json like that :

```
{
    "to": "ExponentPushToken[YOUR_EXPO_PUSH_TOKEN]",
    "badge": 1,
    "body": "You've got mail"
  },
```

),
and it sending directly on IOS(apns) or Android(Firebase)

Outside your class :

```
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
    }),
});
```

In your init function (componentDidMount), set notification:

```
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(this._handleNotification);

        Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(this._handleNotificationResponse);
        //Push Notification init
        await this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
```

registerForPushNotificationAsync()

```
async registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
            finalStatus = status;
        }
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
            return;
        }
        let tokenPush = this.setAndFormatNotificationPushOnBdd();

        this.setState({ expoPushToken: tokenPush });
    } else {
        alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
            name: 'default',
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
        });
    }
};
```

Other functions :

```
_handleNotification = notification => {
    this.setState({ notification: notification });
};

_handleNotificationResponse = response => {
    console.log(response);
};
```

I just show you my Bdd save :

```
async setAndFormatNotificationPushOnBdd(){
    try {
        const tokenPush = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        //On test le token et le régénère si besoin avec cette fonction
        let validToken = await refreshToken(token);
        //Si le retour n'est pas valide, on déconnecte l'utilisateur
        if (!validToken) this.props.navigation.navigate('Disconnect');
        let userInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userInfo');
        let userSession = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userSession');
        let parsedUserSession = JSON.parse(userSession);

        let tokenFormated = tokenPush.data;

        await setNotificationPushId(parsedUserSession.user.n, tokenFormated, token,parsedUserSession)
        return tokenFormated;
    }catch (e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: U just need to follow doc on how to configure expo push with firebase and apns

Comment: How to configure, its ok. But my question is about manage this. How to open some screen when tap on notification.

Comment: in the _handleNotificationResponse() or in _handleNotification, u can treat the notification

Comment: I tried on addNotificationReceivedListener. But this listener fires when the device receives the notification with the application open. And when you receive, the action triggers. I need to trigger the action to open the screen when click on the notification. I'll try addNotificationResponseReceivedListener.